# global hotkeys in C#

Tags: c#, key, hotkeys, getasync

I have always been hardcoding hotkeys using `GetAsyncKeystate()` (hotkey is used to show/hide the Application). 
Now I've been wondering how the automatic keydetection in PC-games works:    [image].
How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by automatic key detection? They are just keys set by default by game and you can change them.

Comment: you click on the option and then it waits until you press a key, detects which key it was and changes the hotkey to the key you just set.

Comment: that depends on the platform you are going to implement this. what are you using? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: I'm trying to implement on WinForms.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you get keypressed event and set string as event args, and save that string as applictacion settings hotkeys.

Comment: I thought about that but this method does not work with combinations like Ctrl+V.

Comment: @nice what about keypressed event fires up string hotkey+=ctrl, event fired again hotkey+=v. Hotkey setting finished save hotkey in app settings.

Comment: and when use each method for diffrenent hotkey